# Why are type annotations needed for generics with defaults, yet Vec in nightly infers its allocator automatically?

Tags: rust

I am trying to define a struct with a defaultable type parameter, the same way Vec works in Rust nightly with its allocator. However, as explained in other answers and the Rust forum, that's not how type inference works:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<X: Copy = i32> {
    x: PhantomData<X>
}

impl<X: Copy> Foo<X> {
    fn new() -> Foo<X> {
        Foo {
            x: PhantomData
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // type annotations needed
    let foo = Foo::new();
    
    // works??
    let mut bar = Vec::new();
    bar.push(42); // to let Rust infer T.
}
```

My question is not why `Foo::new()` does not compile, but rather why `Vec::new()` still does. If I remove `Foo::new()`, the file compiles. As far as I understand it, the new definition of Vec to support allocators should've broken almost all code.

Ideally an answer would point me to the code in rustc that makes this exemption, if it is one.

Comment: Because rust can deduce that Vec must be i32 based on your usage. If you remove `bar.push(42);` it will fail to compile with the same `cannot infer type for type parameter `T`` error

Comment: @IvanC I am asking why the second type parameter to Vec can be inferred, not the first one. Rust recently added support for custom allocators and so the definition of Vec is not `Vec<T>`, but `Vec<T, A: Allocator = Global>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `impl` [in which `fn new` is defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#383-508) is generic over `T`, but not `A`:

```
impl<T> Vec<T> {
    pub const fn new() -> Self {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since `A` has a default of `Global`, this implements a `new` function for `Vec<T, Global>`. It does not implement a `new` function for any other allocator. So `Vec::new` will always create a new `Vec<_, Global>`.

The fact that `A` has a default is actually tangential; that isn't taken into consideration when resolving `Vec::new`.

You can make `Foo` work the same way:

```
impl Foo<i32> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Foo { x: PhantomData }
    }
}
```

Note that in this case `new` will always create a `Foo<i32>`, and if you want a function that creates a different kind of `Foo`, you'll need to create a differently-named function, just as `Vec` has `new_in` for specifying a different allocator than `Global`.